# Modify height after dynamic create with each

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-isotope

I have a fluid composition in columns with isotope:

```
<template name="iso">
     <div class="{{anchor}}">
           <img src="{{image}}"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I filled the template, and I need when the anchor = taller , the width = 25% and the height is the same *2. square is 25% and the same height, and wider is 50% and the height is /2.

in js:

```
template.iso.onRendered= function(){
  $('.square').heigth() = $('.square').width 
  $('.toller').heigth() = $('.square').width * 2
  $('.widen').heigth() = $('.square').width 
};
```

But, onRendered runs before the rendering of the `{{#each}}`, I have all of the divs, but the heights don't change.

Any solution?
(sorry for my English I don't write well)

Comment: Possibly it's simply a misspelling; you have "heigth" which should be "height" Yes, English is a crazy language, but the word is pronounced "hite".

Comment: First you have written `$('.square').heigth()` ..correct it to `$('.square').height()`

Comment: Hello i hope to help, you try add CSS, example:

    .square { height: auto; }

and ever change the content, this adjust

Answer (score 0):

i solve this with

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
    if (!this.rendered){
        //the data is there but dom may not be created yet
                //$("img").unveil();
                var altoBase =  $('.isotope').width() / 5;
                var altoDoble =  altoBase * 2 ;

                $(  ".carta").each(function( i ) {
                    if ($( this).hasClass('alto') ) {
                        $( this ).css({
                            height: altoDoble + 'px',
                            backgroundColor: "green"
                        });
                    } else {
                        $( this ).css({
                            height: altoBase + 'px',
                            backgroundColor: "white"
                        });
                    }
                });
                var self = this;
                self.selection = this.$('.isotope').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.carta',
                    masonry: {
                        gutter: 0
                    }
                });
    }
```

};

this solution is ok for isotope as well